# Why my hover effect does not animate?

Tags: jquery, animation

I am 100% sure I got lost with the jQuery selectors. My hover effect is out of order.

Here is my structure:

```
 <div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="menu_nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Start Page</asp:HyperLink>
          <em>Animate this text</em>
          </li>
          <li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and here is the jQuery that should do the animation:

```
$(".menu_nav ul li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).next("em").animate({ opacity: "show", top: "-75" }, "slow");
}, function () {
    $(this).next("em").animate({ opacity: "hide", top: "-85" }, "fast");
});
```

and this one is the css:

```
.menu_nav ul li em {
    background: url(images/hover.png) no-repeat;
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -85px;
    left: -15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 12px 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your selectors. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/cxQpt/. The problem is that you're trying to set opacity to display the item, which has no meaning. Look at `show`/`hide` or maybe `slideUp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your css but basically you need to change the `opacity` to `1` not `show`

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/6HmyD/)

Note the css change from `display: none` => `opacity: 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/xygHB/

**Change in css**

```
.menu_nav ul li em {
    background: url(images/hover.png) no-repeat;
    width: 180px;
    height: 45px;
    top: -85px;
    left: -15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 12px 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity:0;
}
```

**Change in js**

```
$(".menu_nav ul li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).next("em").animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-75px" }, "slow");
}, function () {
    $(this).next("em").animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-85px" }, "fast");
});
```